# how to control where rpmbuild command puts .rpm files

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I am new to `rpmbuild` command.  I carefully read its manpage and I am experimenting with it.

It is trying to create the `.rpm` files in the `/RPMS` directory, where I don't have permission to write.

How to control where the files are put??

I don't know, maybe it's just me, but I find it very strange that the manpage for a command that creates a file, does not explain where that file is to be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow a setup guide like this one: wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SetupRpmBuildEnvironment

Answer (score 2):

OK, I read that `--showrc` option shows options, and grepped the output of that for `/RPMS`, then read the macro file where that was coming from.  So now I can see, that I can put the following in the `.spec` file

```
%define _rpmdir path/to/my_directory
```